# Updating Other Variable When Variable is Changed in Input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code (snippet example below), I have a variable that is bound to an input box using the `ng-model` directive. Then, I have another variable that, for the purpose of my project, is dependent on that bound variable.

How do I keep (in the case of the example below) `bar` up to date when `foo` changes?

I tried using the `$scope.$watch` function call (which I show the syntax I used below), but the bound function does not get called when the user types something into the input box.

**HTML**

```
...
<div ng-controller="exampleController as ctr">
    ...
    <div><input type="number" ng-model="ctr.foo" /></div>
    <div>{{ ctr.bar }}</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
app.controller('ExampleController', function($scope){
    var local = this;        

    this.foo = 5;
    this.bar = 10;

    this.updateBar = function(){
        this.bar = this.foo * 2;
    };

    $scope.$watch('foo', function(){
        local.updateBar();
    });
});
```

*Note:* All of this is just example code to show what my problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for $watch, if you use `ng-change`? ;)

```
<div ng-controller="exampleController as ctr">
...
  <div><input type="number" ng-model="ctr.foo" ng-change="ctr.updateBar()" /></div>
  <div>{{ ctr.bar }}</div>
</div>
```

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: Didn't even know I could do that tbh. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a scope function:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="exampleController">
    ...
    <div><input type="number" ng-model="foo" /></div>
    <div>{{ bar() }}</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
app.controller('ExampleController', function($scope){      

    $scope.foo = 5;
    $scope.bar = function(){
          return  $scope.foo * 2;
    };

});
```